# angular material md-autocomplete with redirection

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

We have integrated md autocomplete functionality. But our requirement is like, upon selecting any value from md-autocomplete, is it possible to redirect to the corresponding page?

```
<md-autocomplete
        ng-disabled="isDisabled"
        md-no-cache="noCache"
        md-selected-item="selectedItem"
        md-search-text-change="searchTextChange(searchText)"
        md-search-text="searchText"
        md-selected-item-change="selectedItemChange(item)"
        md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
        md-item-text="item.name"
        md-min-length="0"
        placeholder="Search"
        md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template">
        <md-item-template>
          <span class="item-title">
            <!--<md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/octicon-repo.svg"></md-icon>-->
            <span> {{item.name}} </span>
          </span>
        </md-item-template>
    </md-autocomplete>
```

And I had written the function as below:

```
function selectedItemChange(item) {
        $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
        if(item.key == 'doctor'){
            $location.path('/patient/account');
        }
        else if(item.key == 'speciality'){
            $location.path('/patient/account');
        }

    }
```

Its redirecting to the specifieed page, but app getting stuck on that page. Nothing will be working in that page.

But when I try with following, its working perfectly.

```
<div ng-click="testclick()">test</div>
$scope.testclick = function(){
    $location.path('/patient/account');
}
```

When I choose the option from md-autocomplete, its going to the corresponding url. And all the links/buttons will work as normal. Again when i go to the same page and choose another md-autocomplete option,its redirecting to the corresponding page,but the links/buttons in that page is not working. I couldn't able to move from that page. My app gets stuck.

Comment: You can share your code as well in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the page and it's controller in the router. Something like this in your route-controlling js file.

```
 $stateProvider
      .state('root', {
        onEnter: function() {
          //your function you want to trigger
        },
        views: {
          '': {
            templateUrl: 'scripts/base/layout.html',
            controller: 'AppController'
          },
          'somepage@root': {
            templateUrl: 'scripts/base/somepage.html',
            controller: 'NewPageController'
          }
        },

      })
```

Comment: its already specified there:                                                     when('/patient/account', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/patient-account.html',
        controller: 'PatientAccount'
    })

Comment: for me it still looks like you're not passing the right controller to the inherited view, you should maybe show your routing code also..

Comment: angular.module('patientRoutes', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider. when('/patient/account', { templateUrl: 'app/views/patient-account.html', controller: 'PatientAccount' }) .         
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
    
});

Comment: I edited my question. Whenever I choose the options from autocomplete its going to the correponding url. But the links/ buttons inside that page works only for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by Angular Material md-autocomplete. It is a known bug. 
Issue: When using redirect after selecting an item, there will be a md-scroll-mask sit on top of your content with z-index:50. That is why you do not have any control of the next page - no click and scroll.

An easy css fix is to add

```
.md-scroll-mask { position: initial;}
```

If you want to follow up with the official fix, here is the open issue: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3287